# Question on $\operatorname{Var}(nY)$.

Tags: random-variables, variance

I know there’s a simple explanation for this but it’s got me stumped. If I take the variance of $nY$, where Y is a random variable, I have $$\operatorname{Var}(nY) = \operatorname{Var}(\underbrace{Y + Y +\cdots+ Y}_{\text{$n$ times}}) = \underbrace{\operatorname{Var}(Y) + \operatorname{Var}(Y) + \cdots + \operatorname{Var}(Y)}_{\text{$n$ times}}  = n \operatorname{Var}(Y).$$ But variance properties say $\operatorname{Var}(nY) = n^2\operatorname{Var}(Y)$.

Context is I’m using a Bernoulli variable Y with $E(Y) = p$ and $\operatorname{Var}(Y) = p(1-p)$

Then with $X$ = $n$ trials of $Y$, I’m practicing deriving $E(X) = np$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X) = \operatorname{Var}(nY) = n \operatorname{Var}(Y) = np(1-p).$

“$n$” cannot be squared in this case or it will be incorrect according to all sources. How do I reconcile the derivation of the variance in this case with the general property of variance of a random variable multiplied by a scalar?

Really, if you don’t need the context, my entire question is contained in the first paragraph. Why does it seem I can get two different answers for $\operatorname{Var}(nY)$.

Comment: You need to distinguish carefully between $nY$ and the sum of $n$ *independent* copies of $Y$. The two have very different variances!

Comment: In general, the relation $V[X+Y]=V[X]+V[Y]$ is not true of dependent random variables.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true that $var (X+Y)=Var (X) +var (Y)$. So you cannot write $var (nY)=Var(Y)+Var(Y)+...+Var(Y)$. The correct way to find the variance of $nY$ is to use the definition: $var (nY)=E(nY)^{2}-(E(nY))^{2}=n^{2} (EY^{2})-((nEY)^{2})=n^{2} var (Y)$.

Answer (score 0):

Variance is *not* a linear operator.  Rather, Covariance is a Bilinear operator: $$\mathsf{Cov}(S+T,U+V)=\mathsf{Cov}(S,U)+\mathsf{Cov}(S,V)+\mathsf{Cov}(T,U)+\mathsf{Cov}(T,V)$$

---

...and so...

$$\begin{align}\mathsf {Var}(nY) &=\mathsf{Cov}(nY,nY)\\[1ex]&=n\,\mathsf{Cov}(Y,nY)\\[1ex]&=n^2\,\mathsf{Cov}(Y,Y)\\[1ex]&=n^2\,\mathsf{Var}(Y)\end{align}$$

---

When $X=\sum_{k=1}^n Y_k$ where $(Y_k)$ is a sequence of independent and identically *distributed* Bernoulli variables. (Note, that is not identically *valued*.) The *independence* means that the covariance between two distinct members of the sequence is zero, while *identical distribution* means that the variance of any member of the sequence equals the variance of the first member of the sequence.$$\begin{align}\mathsf{Var}(X) &= \mathsf{Cov}(\sum_i Y_i,\sum_j Y_j)\\[1ex]&=\sum_i\sum_j\mathsf{Cov}(Y_i,Y_j)\\[1ex]&=\sum_i\mathsf{Cov}(Y_i,Y_i)+\sum_{i\neq j}\mathsf{Cov}(Y_i,Y_j)\\[1ex]& = n\,\mathsf{Var}(Y_1)+0\end{align}$$

Comment: I greatly appreciate everyone’s input. I know the proof of the scalar squared property of variance, but I’m still bamboozled by the fact that the derivations of the variance of a binomial random variable (assuming independence) that I find online are done the way I showed in my question. The variance is np(1-p), not n^2*p(1-p). I’m still missing something. I think it must come down to what Qiaochu Yuan said, that there’s a difference between nY  and the sum of n independent copies of Y. I just don’t know what that distinction is.

Comment: @KWilliamson: the difference is that they’re different! They’re just not the same at all. In your Bernoulli random variable example the sum of the independent copies amounts to flipping $n$ independent weighted coins, but the sum of the identical copies amounts to flipping a single coin and multiplying the result by $n$.

Comment: Ok, the concrete example helps a lot. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Yeap.  The variance of $n$ times the count the heads shown by one coin,  is going to be *much larger*, than the variance of the count of heads shown by $n$ independent coin.

Comment: Thanks, Graham. I'm new at statistics and sometimes have trouble seeing what's going on behind the scenes. I haven't had that as a major problem with any other kind of math.